# Non-analytic smooth functions and Legendre polynomials

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, hilbert-spaces, analytic-functions, legendre-polynomials

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Definitions): a function $f$ is real analytic on an open set $D$ in the real line if for any $x_0 \in D$ one can write

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 0} ^ \infty a_n (x - x_0) ^ n$$

in which the coefficients $a_0, a_1, ...$ are real numbers and the series is convergent to $f(x)$ for $x$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

Here is an example of a smooth function which is not analytic at the origin $x = 0$ from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#Definition_of_the_function).

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
  e ^ {-\frac{1}{x}} & \text{if } x > 0, \\\\
  0 & \text{if } x \leq 0,
\end{cases}$$

defined for every real number $x$.

The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function#The_function_is_not_analytic): The function $f$ is smooth, and all its derivatives at the origin are $0$. Therefore, the Taylor series of $f$ at the origin converges everywhere to the zero function,

$$\sum_{n = 0} ^ \infty \frac{f ^ {(n)}(0)}{n!} x ^ n = \sum_{n = 0} ^ \infty \frac{0}{n!} x ^ n = 0, \qquad x \in \mathbb{R},$$

and so the Taylor series does not equal $f(x)$ for $x > 0$. Consequently, $f$ is not analytic at the origin.

On the other hand the Legendre polynomials $(P_n)_n$ [form a complete orthogonal system](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre-Polynom#Vollst%C3%A4ndiges_Orthogonalsystem) on the Hilbert space $V = L ^ 2([-1,1];\mathbb{R})$ with the scalar product

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1} ^ 1 f(x) g(x) \mathrm{d} x$$

and $f(x)$ can be written as

$$f(x) = \sum_{n = 0} ^ \infty c_n P_n(x), \qquad x \in [-1,1],$$

hence the function $f$ can be written as a power series.

But why is it $f$ not analytic then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two notions of convergence, pointwise convergence and the $L^2$ convergence differ.

See for instance https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186433/a-e-pointwise-convergence-of-l2-functions-counterexample-for-generalization-o

Comment: Does that mean, that the definition of an analytic function is not very accurate on Wikipedia? There is no restriction to any particular type of convergence in the definition.

Comment: I think the convergence issues are addressed at       https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series. The series is uniformly convergent on every compact set within the radius of convergence and point-wise absolutely  convergent within the radius of convergence. However, the L2 convergence does not necessarily imply either of these convergence properties.